# How do I replace every occurance using AWK statement

Tags: linux, bash, awk

How can I adjust the following code to replace every occurrence of the value set for the element, ThreadGroup.num_threads.

```
Here is the code I'm trying to make work.

  awk ' BEGIN { FS = "[<|>]" }
    {
            if ($2 == "stringProp name=\"ThreadGroup.num_threads\"") {
                   $newValue
            }
            print
    }
    ' Test1.jmx
```

Here is the XML snippet I'm parsing.

```
     <ThreadGroup guiclass="ThreadGroupGui" testclass="ThreadGroup" testname="Thread Group" enabled="true">
    <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.num_threads">3</stringProp>
    </ThreadGroup>
    <ThreadGroup guiclass="ThreadGroupGui" testclass="ThreadGroup" testname="Thread Group2" enabled="true">
    <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.num_threads">3</stringProp>
    </ThreadGroup>



newValue=999999
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, the variable `newValue` is never defined. Moreover, you do not need `$` in front of your own variables.

Here is my suggestion:

```
awk '$0 ~ /stringProp name="ThreadGroup.num_threads"/ 
  {sub(/<stringProp name="ThreadGroup.num_threads">[0-9]+/,
       "<stringProp name=\"ThreadGroup.num_threads\">999999",
        $0)}
   {}1' inputFile
```

**1st line**: I check whether the current line contains the text `stringProp name="ThreadGroup.num_threads"`
**2nd-4th line**: If yes, I substitute the string `<stringProp name="ThreadGroup.num_threads">` if it is followed by one or more numbers by the same string followed by `999999`.
**5th line**: Finally, I output each line.

Of course you can define a variable:

```
awk 'BEGIN{newValue=999999}
     $0 ~ /stringProp name="ThreadGroup.num_threads"/ 
     {sub(/<stringProp name="ThreadGroup.num_threads">[0-9]+/,
          "<stringProp name=\"ThreadGroup.num_threads\">"newValue,
           $0)}
     {}1' inputFile
```

The output is:

```
 <ThreadGroup guiclass="ThreadGroupGui" testclass="ThreadGroup" testname="Thread Group" enabled="true">
<stringProp name="ThreadGroup.num_threads">999999</stringProp>
</ThreadGroup>
<ThreadGroup guiclass="ThreadGroupGui" testclass="ThreadGroup" testname="Thread Group2" enabled="true">
<stringProp name="ThreadGroup.num_threads">999999</stringProp>
</ThreadGroup>
```

Comment: @ F. Knorr  That is really helpful. Thanks. However, on testing it with the following it added an extra 2 lines. I think it might be slightly incorrect.
          <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.num_threads">3</stringProp>
           <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.num_threads">3</stringProp>

Comment: What do you mean by "added an extra 2 lines"? Look at the output I have provided in my answer: is this your desired output?

Comment: instead of updating it appends a new line with the correct values.

Comment: That's strange! Have you copied my code without modifications? Could you try this:  `awk 'BEGIN{newValue=999999}$0 ~ /stringProp name="ThreadGroup.num_threads"/ {a=$0; sub(/<stringProp name="ThreadGroup.num_threads">[0-9]+/,"<stringProp name=\"ThreadGroup.num_threads\">"newValue,a); print a; next;}{}1' inputFile` (If this doesn't work either, try omitting `{}1` in this command)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this is easier with `sed`

```
$ sed -r 's/("ThreadGroup.num_threads">)([0-9]+)</\19999</g'
```